# I want to implement this logic in Java program, tried in many separate ways but haven't found out yet

Tags: java, algorithm

I want a Java program which follows this logic:

```
i  |   j
----------

1  |   1
2  |   3
3  |   6
4  |   10
5  |   15
6  |   21
7  |   28
8  |   36
9  |   45
10 |   55
```

So assuming initially

```
i = 0, j = 0;
i iterates: i++
j iterates: j +=i;
```

I want my program when I type a j value for example 39 to find that I'm between 36 and 45 and the program should get me the i value for that which is 8 (Note that I do not want to get the closest value, I only want the value that already passed from i column)

I tried with this method, but it doesn't work when you want to work with intervals:

```
 List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(6);
        // i-j pairs  --> the problem with this is that it's hardcoded

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter j value: ");
        int inputJ = scanner.nextInt();

        int i = -1; // initialize i to an invalid value
        for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k += 2) { // loop through the list by pairs
            int currentI = list.get(k);
            int currentJ = list.get(k + 1);
            if (currentJ == inputJ)  // find a match
                i = currentI;
            
        }

        if (i == -1) {
            System.out.println("No matching i value found for j = " + inputJ);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The corresponding i value for j = " + inputJ + " is " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the logic, it's two interleaved intervals, you want to traverse each index separately, returning a value at *i*, when a value at *j* is met.

Firstly, I believe the logic should be

```
i is 0
j is 1
i += 2
j += 2
```

For *currentI*, you'll need to subtract 2 from *i*, since meeting the condition for *inputJ* is an additional iteration, thus *+2*.

```java
int[] values = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 4, 10, 5, 15, 6, 21, 7, 28, 8, 36, 9, 45, 10, 55 };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(values.length);
for (int value : values) list.add(value);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter j value: ");
int inputJ = scanner.nextInt();
int currentI = -1, currentJ = -1;
for (int i = 0, j = 1; j < list.size(); i += 2, j += 2) {
    if (list.get(j) > inputJ) {
        currentI = list.get(i - 2);
        currentJ = list.get(j);
        break;
    }
}
```

Demonstration

```
Enter j value: 39
currentI = 8
currentJ = 45
```

Answer (score 0):

The `i` values are a linear progression, and are the differences between the `j` values.

The differences between successive values in a quadratic progression form a linear progression, so you can assume (correctly) that `j` is quadratically related to `i`, and then use 3 known values to find the formula:

j = ai<sup>2</sup> + bi + c =>

1 = a + b + c

3 = 4a + 2b + c

6 = 9a + 3b + c

If you solve these, you find that a = b = 1/2 and c=0, so `j = (i*i + i)/2 = i(i+1)/2`

Let's check: When i = 10, we need j=55: 10*11/2 = 55. Check.

Now, if you solve for `i` given `j`, you get `i = (sqrt(8*y + 1) - 1)/2`

Since you want the next smaller integer value of `i`, it's just `preceding_i = floor((sqrt(8*y + 1) - 1)*0.5)`

Answer (score 0):

For this, instead of maintaining interval variables, you can simply use binary search. If for the current value, sum of `n` natural numbers till current number greater than `J`, go left, else, go on the right side(as in, go for a larger number).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int J = 39;
      int low = 0, high = J;
      int ans = -1;
      while(low <= high){
        int mid = low + ((high - low) / 2);
        int valJ = mid * (mid + 1) / 2;
        if(valJ > J){
          high = mid - 1;
        }else{
          ans = mid;
          low = mid + 1;
        }
      }
      
      System.out.println(J + " -> " + ans);
  }
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3z9x93htk)